# How can I search only those photos which haven't been added to any album on Google Photos?

Tags: search, google-photos

I selected a group of photos and added them to an album.

But now, I want to exclude those photos from my search, because I don't want to add them to another album by mistake and vice versa - I want to add all photos to some album.

I searched on Google, but found nothing.

Do you know any solution?

Comment: AI E., that's true, but I wrote this question earlier than @bgoodr did.

Comment: We don't necessarily make the oldest question the canonical one. The other seems to have more details so I voted that way.

Answer (score 1):

At this time it's not possible.

**References**

- [Google Photos Help](http://support.google.com/photos)

**Other similar posts**

Google Photos Help Forum

- [Search for photos not in any album](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/photos/nVjM-c3t6x0)
- [Is there a way of searching for all photos that are not in an album? Thanks](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/photos/T0S92ZIOqAY)